# Swiper init script for mobile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper 6.4.10 for a project. It's the first time I use Swiper.
This website has multiple sliders on 1 page. So I decided to create some initializing script. I'm using data-attributes to create the slider settings. Every slider has different setups. One of those settings is to run the slider only on a mobile device and destroy it on desktop or tablet.

I've read a whole lot of posts here and in Google but I just can't get it to work.

It is about this part:

```
if(container){
  var initID = '#' + container;
  if(mobile){
   if(mobile_breakpoint.matches){
     var init = new Swiper(this, settings)
   } else if (!mobile_breakpoint.matches){
     var init = this.swiper.destroy();
   }
  }
  //var init = new Swiper(initID, settings)
}
```

When I use this code here above then all carousels are destroyed OR I get an error saying `this.swiper.destroy` is `undefined`.
When I run my code like this:

```
if(container){
  var initID = '#' + container;
  var init = new Swiper(initID, settings)
}
```

Then all carousels just work. When I check for data attribute `mobile` and try to destroy the carousels then all stop working. I clearly miss something out.

Anybody have any idea what I do wrong? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Your mistake" under `else if` you forgot first to Initialize `swiper instance` .

This is why when you uncomment this block of code - the page is broken (error: `this.swiper.destroy is undefined`).

[image]

To **destroy** an instance you first should create this instance ([destroy()](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties) is a Method of [swiper instance](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper)).

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {});
swiper.destroy();
```

Otherwise, your code is like writing:

```
bla_bla.destroy(); /* Uncaught ReferenceError: bla_bla is not defined */
```

1. Create an instance (Missing in your code)
2. Destroy

```
else if (!mobile_breakpoint.matches){
   var init = new Swiper(this, settings) /* missing in your code */
   init = this.swiper.destroy();
}
```

In general - your code is very long ==> next time [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (A lot of code not related to your issue/error).

Comment: Thx for your answer. You are right about the long code but I tried to create a fiddle but somehow all code is added. I removed it thx. About your suggestion... That doest work indeed. Do you perhaps have a better idea to accomplish my idea? Or is the way I did it a good way to have multiple sliders on one page? Anyway thx for the help!